# Laravel - Hash input using SHA512

Tags: laravel, api, sha512

I am creating an API POST request, but I want to hash some of the user input (referenceID and phone_no) and save into hash field using SHA512. I want to put it in the Controller.

I have create the Model Class and also the Controller

Model

```
    protected $fillable = [
        'referenceID' ,
        'phone_no',
        'hash'
    ];
```

Controller

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'referenceID' => 'required',
            'phone_no' => 'required',
        'hash' => 'required'
        ]);

        $valrequest = Task::create($request->all());

        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Great success! New validation request created',
            'valrequest' => $valrequest, 201
        ]);
    }
```

I want to hash the user input (referenceID and phone_no) and save into the hash field using SHA512. I want to put it in the Controller. How do I do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should work fine like this, but the code's not tested at all and there's like a million different ways to do this. You won't need to validate the hash because it's no user input.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'referenceID' => 'required',
        'phone_no' => 'required',
    ]);

    $referenceID = $request->referenceID;
    $phone_no = $request->phone_no;
    $hash = hash('sha512', $referenceID . $phone_no);

    $valrequest = Task::create(compact('referenceID', 'phone_no', 'hash'));

    return response()->json([
        'message' => 'Great success! New validation request created',
        'valrequest' => $valrequest, 201
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Laravel hash provides Bcrypt and Argon2 hashing. If you want to use sha512 you should use php hashing function. `hash("sha512","your string");`